# ready api report and NullPointerException

Tags: soapui, ready-api

Can someone please help me with follwoing two issues i am seeing in ready api.

- When i run the project thru testRunner, i see a nullpointerexpcetion
  thrown at the end (attached screenshot)
- When i run my project manually, generate rport button is disabled.
  enter image description here
  [image]

Comment: Can you post the full command line options you're using for testrunner? Do any of the other log tabs along the bottom of the UI give you any more information about what's happening?

Comment: "C:\Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-2.4.0\bin\testrunner.bat" -r -j "-fC:\Users\M.P\Desktop\SOAP UI Smoke Suite Report" -g -o "-RJUnit-Style HTML Report" -FXML "-EDefault environment" -I "C:\Users\M.P\Desktop\SMOKE-SUITE\Rest-API-readyapi-project"

Comment: No other information is given in bottom tabs

Answer (score 0):

I unchecked enable coverage checkbox under project coverage from UI and from preferences reporting and restarted readyapi and no longer see the issues.